# Build ionic | Cannot find module '../plugman/platforms/ios'

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

Please I'm facing a problem when I'm building an Ionic App on iOS using: `ionic cordova build ios`

This is the error I'm getting:

```
CHCP plugin after prepare hook:
    config-file preference is not set.
(node:19165) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module '../plugman/platforms/ios'
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The error says you are missing your config-file setting. At the bottom of this plugin's [README](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-hot-code-push) instructions it says you must set the config-file. Add the file in the correct format and that should fix this specific error.